# How to implement double click event handling into Android SDK source code [PhoneWindow.java]

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement double click event handling into Android SDK (phoneWindow.java) for emulator hardkey.
There i am able to see the click and longpress event handling but no idea about double click event handling into SDK source code.

Please help to implement this feature.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
long lastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
static final long MAX_DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME = 150;

boolean isDoubleClick(){
    boolean result = false;
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(now - lastClickTime <MAX_DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME){
        result = true;
    }
    lastClickTime = now;
    return result;
}
```

Call that function in your onClick handler.  It will return true for a double click.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good site for performing double click... I used it and worked.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/

We should implement a `GestureDetector` and `GestureListener`.

```
private class GestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,  
        GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {  
     PlayAreaView view;  
     public GestureListener(PlayAreaView view) {  
        this.view = view;  
     }  
}
```

This should do the trick. Go through the tutorial and you would be able to implement it properly and also many other gestures :)

Cheers.

Comment: I can't use GestureListener in SDK Source code ,PhoneWindow.java

Comment: see the tutorial it is elaborately explained. You would understand the imports and all too there. I just gave an example as to how it would look.

Comment: Ankit,you are correct but i want to handle into SDK Source means android kernal side.So there is not feasible to use GestureListener concepts there.Like we have longpress event also have code implementation there also.thanks for your quick reply